# get_context_data not getting called

Tags: python, django

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = '...html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

        return super(BaseView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ConfigureView(BaseView):
    form_class = Form
    template_name = 'configure.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(user=request.user)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'form': form
        })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('...')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('**********')  # Never printed

        context = super(ConfigureView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['app'] = App.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])

        return context
```

Why? I think I am following the docs.

Comment: Is this your actual code? There's no error here, so you should show a little bit more of your actual code to help you.

Comment: @Gocht is a minimum version. And I don't get any error.

Comment: This an extrem 'minimum'. Consider sharing more code.

Comment: @Gocht I added more. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a `render` in your `.get()` method, this method (`render`) receives a context as a param, it does not call `.get_context_data()`, you need to do this:

```
...
get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    return super(ConfigureView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @AdamSilver Now you can see why more code were needed, please, keep that in mind the next time you post a question.

Comment: I do :) So now I have to pass the 'form' in context method?

Comment: Why don't you use a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview)?

Comment: I will give it a go.

Comment: can i ask, how th eform will be render, i try this but my form is hidden as the return doesnt have the render(request, self.template_name, 'form': form})  thanks

Comment: @Manza returning a render object is needed when working with functions based views.

Answer (score -1):

You can instantiate the class, and call the method

```
ConfigureView().get_context_data()
```

or

```
instance = ConfigureView()
instance.get_context_data()
```

that should get to the print command